# Simulators missing in Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, apple-tv

After updating to Xcode 10.3, I found some of my simulators were missing. Trying to manually add one from Window -> Devices and Simulators produced a error.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the computer worked for me.

Comment: Tried to download more simulators -> check and install now. Checked the automatic checkbox. Found this post, restarted, now i have a list of simulators again. :)